# Gedit prints Tepl-WARNING on save

Tags: gedit

I'm fairly new to Linux systems and i just installed an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a separate drive.

When i use gedit to work on my files it prints the following warning when i save it:

`(gedit:6645): Tepl-WARNING **: 16:46:07.942: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata.`

It does it regardless of whether or not I use my user account, use sudo or execute as root.

There is one similar thread where the answer is to execute with sudo -H gedit file, but that does not work for me. It still displays the warning message. It does not prevent the program from running, but the warning is annoying and i would like for it to not show at all if possible.

Any help on the topic would be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance!